# Is it ok to unlock a mutex twice in Qt 5.4?

Tags: c++, qt

The code is as following:

```
waitmutex.lock(); //waitmutex is a QMutex
int tout=4000;
if(!waitc.wait(&waitmutex,tout))//waitc is a QWaitCondition
{
    waitmutex.unlock(); // unlock first time
    mutex.lock();
    if(tileCacheQueue.count()==0)
    {
        mutex.unlock();
        break;
    }
    mutex.unlock();
}
waitmutex.unlock();// unlock the second time possibly?
```

Will the code possibly results in the waitmutex to be unlocked twice?
Is this a problem in Qt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmutex.html#unlock) this is undefined behavior:

> `void QMutex::unlock()`
>
> Unlocks the mutex. Attempting to unlock a mutex in a different thread
>   to the one that locked it results in an error. **Unlocking a mutex that
>   is not locked results in undefined behavior.**

Emphasis mine.

While I'm not entirely certain what your code is doing, you should consider using [QMutexLocker](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmutexlocker.html) for one or both mutexes to make your code exception safe.

Comment: Would you mind to have a look at the code above to see whether it is possible for the unlock function to be called twice?

Comment: yes, if `titleCacheQueue.count()` is greater than 0 then `waitmutex.unlock()` could be called twice.